# Finalbuilder trigger update repositiry from mapped drive

Tags: git, finalbuilder

We store some git repositories on local fileservers. On finalbuilder-server I made a "Git-Trigger" which should trigger the build when repository is updated.
I checked the option "Update from remote repository:". On "Remote repository:" I set "X:\pathToRemoteRepo".
X:\ as mapped drive should be available for the trigger by setting the option "Map Network Share".

I always get error:

> Could not update respository
>   C:\pathToLocalRepo from
>   X:\pathToRemoteRepo. 1 : fatal:
>   'X:\pathToRemoteRepo' does not appear
>   to be a git repository fatal: The
>   remote end hung up unexpectedly

Another approach was to set "X:\pathToRemoteRepo" as "Repository location" to observe. But the error was:

> The repository location specified does
>   not exist

Perhaps this occours because X:\pathToRemoteRepo is a bare Repo?

I simply want to monitor a git bare repository (with a finalbuilder git trigger) which is located on a mapped network share. Should be easy ...

Answer (score 0):

By Default FinalBuilder runs as the system process which means it does not have access to network resources like mapped drives.

To change this setting login as the administrator into the web interface.

Then Select Administration and Configuration then under Global Project Settings
You need to set an Impersonation User Name and Password.

Domain User are entered using USER@DOMAIN syntax.

Update: Mapped drives have been painful at best when working with the server version of FinalBuiler.   It's always easier to use UNC. \SERVERNAME\PATH

Comment: Hi Robert. Thanks for your answer. The user-settings have already been set. The solution was to set an unc path: \\server\share\remoteRepo.

Comment: Do you knowh how to tell the trigger to monitore a special branch in the local repository. It only tiggers changes in the "master". But we want to trigger our "development_branch". I tried "Remote branch" but this option seems to work only for pulling a remote repository before tigger the changes in the "Repository location:".

Comment: I have not used GIT in a trigger situation, so I am not familiar with how to do that.